# Python 3 error - TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im a beginner in python 3... I'm currently practicing with exercises and I got this error while doing this.

```
contadorbi=0  
contadornobi=0  
primer_antildeo=int(input("Escriba primer a&ntildeo: "))  
while True:  
     segundo_antildeo=int(input("Escriba segundo a&ntildeo posterior a",primer_antildeo, ": "))
```

Ignore the first 2 lines, its part of the code but not relevant...

Basically, in this line of the code:

> segundo_antildeo=int(input("Escriba segundo a&ntildeo posterior a",primer_antildeo, ": "))

It gives me the error you see on the title...What can I do to solve it?

I tried doing

> segundo_antildeo=int(input("Escriba segundo a&ntildeo posterior a"+primer_antildeo+": "))

I checked other answers and it worked this way, but for me it doesnt seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**primer_antildeo** is an Integer type. So instead of

```
segundo_antildeo=int(input("Escriba segundo a&ntildeo posterior a"+primer_antildeo+": "))
```

try this:

```
segundo_antildeo=int(input("Escriba segundo a&ntildeo posterior a" + str(primer_antildeo) + ": "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The input function can only take one argument.

[Python input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

I think you might be trying to do this:

```
something1 = input()
something2 = input()
something3 = something1 + something2
```

Answer (score 0):

The input function can only take one argument. In your case, you want to concatenate strings inside the input function, You can try:

```
segundo_antildeo=int(input("Escriba segundo a&ntildeo posterior a {}:".format(primer_antildeo)))
```